# Eigenvectors of the matrix [0 1; 0 0]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can I find the eigenvectors of the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
        0&  1 \\
                0 & 0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}

I found the eingenvalues $+i$ and $-i$, and the eigenvector $0$, but it's not possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Those aren't the eigenvalues...

Comment: How did you find those eigenvalues?

Answer (score 3):

The characteristic polynomial is only $p(t) = t²$, so $0$ is the only eigenvalue. And solving: $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$gives $b = 0$, so $(1,0)$ is one eigenvector which spans the one-dimensional eigenspace associated to $0$. In particular, that matrix is not diagonalizable.